# Asp.NET Core Web API : прекращается валидация

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть модель

```
public class Model
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(6), MinLength(6)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(3)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int? User { get; set; }
    }
```

Если я передаю некорректные данные в полях User, Color и Text, то в ответ такой:

```
{
    "code": "VALIDATION",
    "fields": [
        {
            "field": "user",
            "error": "INVALID"
        }
    ]
}
```

Получается, что валидация останавливается после проверки поля User и в ответ уходит только оно. Если же в поле User отправить корректные данные, то в ответе уже придет  информация об остальных ошибках. 
Вопрос. Как сделал так чтобы информация обо всех ошибках приходила сразу?